# Materialize active record object with included associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a basic active query like so:

```
m = Movie.includes(:genres)
```

`m.genders` is an `CollectionProxy` in this case. Is there a way I can get this as an array?

I know that calling `to_a` will do this, but this becomes impractical for a bunch of includes.

Comment: `CollectionProxy` already acts like an Array, why do you need to convert it?

Comment: @infused if I cache `m` then it will execute the select from genders next time I fetch the cached value

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this

```
Movie.includes(:genders).joins(:genders).all
```

It will include all your genders using join so there will be just one query to get all movies and their genders.

Note that your Movie model should have

```
has_many :genders
```

And your Gender model should have

```
belongs_to :movies
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not answer my question really, `m.genres` will still be a CollectionProxy and caching it does not work.

Comment: I think you should update the your question since it doesn't mention the cache. Caching will actually work. Just put your item into the cache like this: Rails.cache.write(:movies, Movies.includes(:genders).joins(:genders).all) and then read it like this: Rails.cache.read(:movies). It will evaluate the SQL just once when you iterate for the first time. If you want to evaluate the SQL at the moment of write then just append to_a. Also please make sure the caching is enabled (by default in development it is disabled). You can do it like this: config.action_controller.perform_caching = true.